# How do I tell hook_block() about placement

Tags: blocks, 7

I may have a disconnect and I'm just not sure if what I'm asking is possible. I'd like to tell Drupal where to place a block. So far I'm using a Context with a path condition to `user/*` and `stream`.

[image]

Can't I accomplish the similar thing with the following?

```
function hook_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {

  if ($op == 'list') 
  {
    $blocks[0] = array(
      'info'      => t('Social Login Block'),
      'region'    => 'sidebar_last',
      'pages'     => 'stream\nusers/*',
      );
```

Is this possible or is it better form to just let the maintainer set the block manually? Or a larger question, how might I translate this context rule into code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [hook_block_info_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info_alter/7) instead of hook_block(). For example:

```
function YOURMODULE_block_info_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks) {
  $blocks['MODULE']['BLOCK']['visibility'] = BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED;
  $blocks['MODULE']['BLOCK']['pages'] = 'user/* \n stream';
}
```

Where `YOURMODULE` is the name of your module, `MODULE` is the module generating the block, and `BLOCK` is the name of the block. You should list all paths where the block should be visible separated by `\n`, `\r` or `\n\r`.